# Android 4.0 and custom title bar is not working

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I have a application for android 2.3.3 where I am setting some custom titles like this:

```
final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

if ( customTitleSupported ) 
  {
     getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);
  }

myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle);

if ( myTitleText != null ) 
  {
     myTitleText.setText("MDPI - Main");
  }
```

All those lines are writen in onCreate().

In android 2.3.3, all is working fine. I am now trying to make the same application for android 4.0 but i have a problem with setting custom title bar. I am gotting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(4225): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
```

I need help to resolve this error.

My class is defined like this:

```
MDPIActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener, AnimationListener
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved this with setting another theme, like thise one:

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"

in the AndroidManiest file.